# After running "apt-get upgrade" my kali is broken

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade

To be brief and to the point after running "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade" my default terminal has changed to the one on the right and the terminal that opens with "open terminal here" (in the right-click menu) looks like the one on the left, which looks so ugly and small that I can barely read anything on it.

So how can I manually change the terminals?

[image]

Comment: How do you open your terminal? Do you use CTRL-ALT-T?

Comment: I click on the terminal icon or right click then open terminal here. Besides, since I thought the root of the problem might be the command I run, I thought that would be smarter to just mention the causes of the command and ask how to manually fix the issues that were caused by it.